# How do I stack TNT minecarts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently on Reddit I have been seeing a *lot* of sculk mines. They appear to be pretty easy to make once you have the necessary parts, so I decided to make some.

I have come across a bit of a problem. In the videos showing how to build these, they have multiple TNT minecarts on the same segment of rail. I tried doing this, and it doesn't work; I can't place another TNT minecart on the rail once one is already there.

How do I do this?

EDIT: I would like to be able to do this without commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place a rail you can dig down in front of it, sneak and hold right click on the rail with the tnt minecart in hand. Be careful though, tnt minecarts are highly unstable.

Answer (score 3):

Aim at the hitbox of the rail, below the minecart, not at the minecart. Watch for the thin black outline - it appears when the rail is in focus, and you can add minecarts to it. It will only be available from the side - front and back are obstructed by the minecart overhanging it, same for access from above. No need to sneak or dig, but don't nudge the minecarts placed that way or they'll be picking bits of you over in farlands.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `/summon minecraft:tnt_minecart` you can make more tnt minecarts if you use the /summon command.

Comment: It think he mentioned that he did NOT want to use commands...

Comment: @AyushBhatt. I added that reply before he added the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dispensers. The dispensers should point toward the rail put tnt Minecart in the dispensers. after that power the dispensers.